# Ultra-light gzip compression implementation?

Tags: c++, gzip

I'm searching for an ultra-light gzip compression/decompression library in C++ (something definitively lighter than zlib) on a libral (BSD, MIT, PD) license. Googling revealed many libraries, but either they are bloated (like GZ compression in Crypto++) or on a more restrictive license.

It's hard to believe for me, that there's no lightweight free gz implementation...

Preferably C++ (I need to have it in the form of a stream) but C would be ok.

Comment: are you stuck with gzip compression?

Comment: Not exactly. But if I'd choose another one, it'd need to be one that is widely supported (AS3, PHP, Python).

Comment: I was about to mention LibLZF and FastLZ but i don't think they provide bindings for other languages than C and C++

Comment: What's not lightweight about zlib? Is it in terms of code size? Or in terms of API? zlib has a simplified API where you can (de)compress an in-memory byte stream into another buffer with a single function call.

Comment: If the algorithm is supported in other languages that's enough. I just want it to be lightweight from C++'s side.

Comment: lightweight in what way? code size?

Comment: Lightweight in code-size sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Statically linked zlib is probably the lightest you can get, it also has a rather nice and generously permissive license.

If it really isn't light enough, even considering what the linker will strip out, then chopping it down to size yourself might be a viable option.

Comment: it's the source distribution size that I'm also concerned about. Ideally I'd like to additionally include two or four additional files with the library.

Comment: If the number of source files bother you that much then hacking away at zlib I think you could quite easily combine, for example, all the headers into one or two files, and the implementation files into one or two more.
Can I ask why you care about the number of source files so much? It is an unusual requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at [CGZip, a C++ wrapper for gzip methods](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/cgzip.aspx)?

Comment: I don't want to link to zlib.

Answer (score 0):

[zlib utility functions](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html#Utility%20functions)

These are pretty lightweight. Generally all it takes is a single function call, assuming all your data is already in the appropriate buffers, which should be easy enough. If you want something even more lightweight than this (which may not be in the grand scheme of things as you potentially need to manage more dependencies), what klamlaluno posted looks good.

Comment: as noted before -- I don't want to link to zlib, I want to statically compile *into* my project a barebone lightweight simple gz compression and decompression.

Comment: Then why don't you use a static zlib library and link it statically? The linker then will take only the parts of the library that your application uses.

Comment: because I need to distribute the source code of my library also.

Comment: zlib's license permits that. I don't see the problem.